# Power Query: Detect null created by Table.NestedJoin JoinKind.FullOuter

Tags: excel, powerquery

With `Table.NestedJoin JoinKind.FullOuter`, a `null` may be written into columns when there is a value in the right table "key" that does not exist in the left table "key".

However, unlike a null that is in the left table because the cell is empty, this created null does not = True with the formula `[column] = null`.

For example:

**Table1**
*Note the null in row 3*
[image]

**Table2**
[image]

**Joined Table**
*The null in row 5 was created as a result of the Join*
[image]

**Custom Column**
*added with formula `=[A]=null`*
*note the different results for the null*
[image]

**MCode** *to reproduce the above*

```
let
    Source1 = Table.FromRecords({
        [A="a"],
        [A="b"],
        [A=null],
        [A="c"]
    }),
    type1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source1,{"A", type text}),
    Source2 = Table.FromRecords({
        [A="c"],
        [A="d"]
    }),
    type2 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{"A", type text}),

    combo = Table.NestedJoin(type1,"A",type2,"A","joined",JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(combo, "Custom", each [A]=null)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Explanations and suggestions as to how to deal with this would be appreciated.

**Edit** In addition to the above, doing a `Replace` will also only replace the `null` in row 3, and not the `null` in row 5. Seems there is something different about these two nulls.

**Note:** If I **Expand** the table, the *null* in Column A will now test correctly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the outcome if you use `[A] is null`, or even `([A] as null) = null`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert That did not work either.  One way that seemed to work with both *null*s was `List.Count(List.RemoveNulls({[A]}))=0`, but that seems a rather awkward method, and certainly not in accord with documentation I have found.  And it doesn't handle other issues, like the inability of `Replace` to work.

Comment: Has all the hallmarks of a bug then. I was thinking that maybe somehow a `nothing` value got created, but that should have been weeded out with an explicit `null` conversion. A comparison with `null` should yield only a `true` or `false` regardless of types involved, not `null`, as PQ does not use SQL's three-valued logic.

Comment: @JeroenMostert The problem turns out to probably be a consequence of PQ's evaluation model. In any event, by forcing evaluation with a Buffer function, the two *null*s behave the same.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking the same question on the Microsoft Q&A forum pointed me to the possibility of an issue with the Power Query [Evaluation model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/evaluation-model) and also this article on [Lazy Evaluation and Query Folding in Power BI/Power Query](https://www.poweredsolutions.co/2019/03/19/lazy-evaluation-query-folding-in-power-bi-power-query/).

By **forcing evaluation** of the table with `Table.Buffer`, both nulls now behave the same.

So:

```
let
    Source1 = Table.FromRecords({
        [A="a"],
        [A="b"],
        [A=null],
        [A="c"]
    }),
    type1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source1,{"A", type text}),
    Source2 = Table.FromRecords({
        [A="c"],
        [A="d"]
    }),
    type2 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{"A", type text}),

//Table.Buffer forces evaluation
    combo = Table.Buffer(Table.NestedJoin(type1,"A",type2,"A","joined",JoinKind.FullOuter)),

//IsItNull now works
    IsItNull = Table.AddColumn(combo, "[A] = null", each [A] = null)
  in
    IsItNull
```

[image]

It also seems to be the case that `try ... otherwise` will also force an evaluation.  So instead of Table.Buffer, the following also works:

```
    ...
    combo = Table.NestedJoin(type1,"A",type2,"A","joined",JoinKind.FullOuter),
//try ... otherwise seems to force Evaluation
    IsItNull = Table.AddColumn(combo, "[A] = null", each try [A] = null otherwise null)
```

Comment: Quite counterintuitive -- you would expect lazy evaluation to stop being lazy once you actually compare a column value, since we clearly need it at that point :P The second approach is arguably the best in terms of giving PQ the most leeway to keep evaluation of the other columns lazy (since we only ask for the value of one), though it may not make a difference in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting case. Indeed, the behaviour of last null is counterintuitive in most possible implementations. If you wish to get the same behaviour for both kinds of nulls, try this approach:

```
= Table.AddColumn(combo, "test", each [A] ?? 10)
```

[image]

Quite interesting, the similar code doesn't work:

```
= Table.AddColumn(combo, "test", each if [A] = null then 10 else [A])
```

[image]

Moreover, if we want to improved the previous code by using the first syntax we still get unexpectable result (10 instead of 20 for the last null):

```
= Table.AddColumn(combo, "test", each if [A] = null then 10 else [A] ?? 20)
```

[image]

Сurious, applying **??** operator also fixes the problem with initial column. Now there are regular nulls in A column:

```
= Table.AddColumn(add, "test2", each [A] = null)
```

[image]

So, if we don't need any calculations and just want to fix invalid nulls, we may use such code:

```
= Table.TransformColumns(combo, {"A", each _ ?? _})
```

The column doesn't matter and for **joined** column the result is the very same:

```
transform = Table.TransformColumns(combo, {"joined", each _ ?? _}),
add = Table.AddColumn(transform, "test", each [A] = null)
```

[image]

Comment: Problem may have to do with the Evaluation Model.  See my answer below

Comment: I do not know how to correctly name the source of the problem, but fact is that after FullOuter join we have defective null, which even doesn't have a type (this becomes clear after applying this code, for example - Table.TransformColumns(combo, {"A", Value.Type})). About overcoming this problem, it may be a matter of taste, but I'd prefer the solution with ?? operator, so, I extended my answer.

Comment: I would think any operation that forces an eager evaluation would work.